# about encryption and decryption using Crypto++ library

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptoapi

Can anyone please give a sample code for encryption and decryption of a text file using Crypto++ library..
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is a c++ library, not a c one.

Comment: I believe the sdk still has examples.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on Code Project of encrypting log files with Crypto++. Hope this helps.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/logit.aspx